fx option atm and delta conventions for G10
I want to know about,
G10 + USDKRW, USDHKD
Fx option quote conventions

ATM convention(for short/long maturities)
Delta convention (unadjusted vs p.a. / spot delta vs forward delta)


If you have Bloomberg, go to OVDV - settings - conventions.
